# how to build qt for arm using cross compilar called xlinu-gcc

Tags: qt

I want to build qt-4.7.4 open source for the arm platform using cross compilar named xlinux-gcc. Can any body tell me the steps to follow and also the commands to be used on the linux terminal. I am using linux mint - 13 as my workstation. I got some help from the internet but as i am a begineer i am very confused. Please help me to build qt. Also can you tell me how to add opengls es2 support in it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a qmake specification file for your platform. Go into the mkspec directory and look the qmake.conf files written for similar platforms. Do the same for yours. You'll have to specify some variables to indicate your compiler, your sysroot, the location of specific libraries etc... Some of those variables are those needed to add es2 support. Also, when configuring, add the parameter -opengl es2. The summary at the end of the configure script will tell you if OpenGL ES 2 is enabled.